# C# Xamarin Forms - Null reference exception after end of the button clicked method

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

I have an Android App in Xamarin Forms and in the app I have this buttons.
They all work perfectly, but the "cleanButtonPressed" method in the "btnClear" button have a little problem.

**XAML:**

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnSaveStock" Text="Salva" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="btnSaveStock_Clicked" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnClear" Text="Pulisci" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="cleanButtonPressed" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnCloseList" Text="Chiudi lista" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="btnCloseList_Clicked"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
```

When I press the button the method PulisciControlli() executes perfectly, and hits the breakpoint without any exception
[image: BreakpointSuccessful]

But when I press F11 it generates immediately the exception.
[image: NullReferenceException]

PulisciControlli, if not called from this method, works perfectly.
They are not present binding, resources dictionary... ecc in the XAML.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**
PulisciControlli actually doing this:

```
private void PulisciControlli()
        {
            etyArticolo.Text = "";
            etyGiacenza.Text = "";
            etyRealGiacenza.Text = "";
            etyArticolo.Text = "";
            etyArticolo2.Text = "";
            etyFornitore.Text = "";

            matricolaSelezionata = null;
            ubicazioneSelezionata = null;

            pckUbicazioni.ItemsSource = null;
            pckUbicazioni.IsVisible = false;

            pckMatricole.ItemsSource = null;
            pckMatricole.IsVisible = false;

            etyArticolo2.IsEnabled = false;
            etyFornitore.IsEnabled = false;

            stcArticolo2.IsVisible = false;
            stcFornitore.IsVisible = false;
            stcOtherFields.IsVisible = false;

            etyArticolo.Focus();
        }
```

Comment: Could you share stack trace from the exception?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Stacktrace reports only "(External Code)"

Comment: Nope, TheTanic
I am not acting on null properties, and when the exception generates is after the closed bracket of the button clicked method

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: Yes, it was to make to understand that the cursor hits the close bracket successfully before crashing

Comment: We need to figure out which line causes the error , did you try to add breakpoint inside the method `PulisciControlli` ? If problem persists , you can remove all the code from the method and see the result .

Comment: Hi cole, I tried and the method PulisciControlli works well as you can see from the first screenshot. 

Trying to remove PulisciControlli from the button and leaving the method blank, the button has no problems. But PulisciControlli called from other method does not give problems, it had problems only called from the button

Comment: This is weird , could you provide a basic , minimal ,reproducible project to use for test ? You can just upload to github and attach the link here .